# Using =HYPERLINK("url", "text") shows 0 in cell instead of "text" on document load

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I must be doing something wrong, I'm not great at Excel in general so this is probably a novice mistake.

Excel version: Microsoft Excel for Mac, Version 16.82 (24021116)

Building a document using `=HYPERLINK()` for cells with links.  Document has over 70k cells with links, so it appears that using this function (formula?) is the suggested workaround for the 65530 link limit in a single sheet.  **Perhaps this is my mistake and there's a better alternative?**

Anyway, the document is built with what appears to be valid cell values, e.g.,

```
=HYPERLINK("https://my.url.com/somepath/Endpoint_ID","Text to display")
```

However, when opening the .xlsx file, the displayed value in the cell is simply "0".  The default formatting for the cell is "General", trying various other formatting has no effect.  The cell can be clicked and the link works, but the display value is just absent.

If I copy/paste this into a different cell, it appears to show the text, without link styling (i.e., not blue, not underlined).

If I edit the value of the cell at all, either the URL or the text portion, the cell will then display the text value with link styling.

At this point, if I save and re-open the spreadsheet, any cells that I edited or copy/pasted show the correct values they did after editing.  Untouched cells still show "0"

Am I missing a setting somewhere?  I'm not sure what other path to pursue at this point.